# postgresql - how to send a parameter as a table in a function?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using postgresql, I would like to know how to send a parameter as a table in a function.

I have already created the type type_detalle_ac:

```
CREATE TYPE public.type_detalle_ac AS
(
 id_componente integer,
 precio numeric(10,2),
 cantidad integer,
 sub_total numeric(10,2)
);
```

and I use it in the following function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.sp_adm_artefacto(
v_serie character varying DEFAULT NULL::character varying,
v_tipo_artefacto integer DEFAULT NULL::integer,
v_modelo character varying DEFAULT NULL::character varying,
v_marca integer DEFAULT NULL::integer,
v_detalle type_detalle_ac DEFAULT NULL::type_detalle_ac,
v_usuario integer DEFAULT NULL::integer,
v_id_artefacto integer DEFAULT NULL::integer,
v_tipo_operacion character DEFAULT NULL::bpchar)
RETURNS void
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'

COST 100
VOLATILE 
ROWS 0
AS $BODY$

DECLARE 

    VL_ID_ARTEFACTO INTEGER;
BEGIN
    IF V_TIPO_OPERACION = 'I' THEN

        INSERT INTO DETALLE_AC(ID_DETALLE_AC,ID_ARTEFACTO,ID_COMPONENTE,PRECIO,CANTIDAD,SUB_TOTAL,
                               USUARIO_CREACION,FECHA_CREACION)
        SELECT 1,1,ID_COMPONENTE,PRECIO,CANTIDAD,SUB_TOTAL,v_usuario,NOW() FROM V_DETALLE;

    END IF;

END;


$BODY$;
```

But when calling the function:

```
SELECT "sp_adm_artefacto"('1321321',1,'F-14',1,(1,10,5,50),1,NULL,'I')
```

I get an error :

```
ERROR:  no existe la relación «v_detalle»
LINE 3: ...NTE,PRECIO,CANTIDAD,SUB_TOTAL,v_usuario,NOW() FROM V_DETALLE
```

Thank you

Comment: It seems the errors says the `v_detalle` table doesn't exist and it's not about the type. Do you have such table?

Comment: hi Abelisto, 
I already added more information

Comment: hello kaveh, v_detalle is the type_detalle_ac parameter

Comment: I worked, thanks  Abelisto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are five sources of data in the `FROM` clause:

- Table
- View
- Values (`select * from (values(1,'a'),(2,'b')) as t(x,y);`)
- Set returning functions ([link](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-srf.html))
- Subqueries

For your question: [Laurenz already answered about `values` way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49076374/593144)

Yet another way, shorter and more general but probably slower a bit:

```
select * from (select variable.*) as t;
```

It transforms your variable to table-like subquery.

Answer (score 1):

`v_detalle` is not a table, so you cannot use it in the `FROM` clause of a query.

You should write

```
INSERT INTO detalle_ac (...)
VALUES (1, 1, v_detalle.id_componente, v_detalle.precio, ...);
```